# Use a variable to find another variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

I have been working on a program involving user input via an `<input>` element, and wanted to do something where depending on what they typed, it changed a different variable, with something like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
var a = "ac";
var b = "bc";
var c = "cc";
alert(input)//Where input is replaced once ran with what is inputed, so if a is typed it alerts "ac"
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="a" />
```

Obviously, the above example does not work, but is there a way where it would?

Comment: Look for event listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the variables in an object instead and dynamically access its properties based on the input.

```js
const obj = {
  a: "ac",
  b: "bc",
  c: "cc"
};
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const val = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  console.log(obj[val]);
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="a" />
<button>Get value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Super simple version but you probably need more for mismatches/no matches etc.

Here I put an event listener on the input for change and then ran a comparison, only alerting when it started with the input.  Try also "ac" etc.

```js
function checkStartsWith(value, arrayValue) {
  return arrayValue.startsWith(value);
}
document.getElementById('myInput')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    let inputValue = this.value;
    const values = [
      "ac", "bc", "cc"
    ];
    values.forEach((element) => {
      let hasValue = checkStartsWith(inputValue, element);
      console.log(hasValue, element);
      if (hasValue) {
        alert(element);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" /> enter something
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution - Add an event listener to the input field, which we can then use to check for user input and display the required alert.

I have added the solution to this CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bessie-tp8vnn

Comment: Consider putting the code IN your answer perhaps as a functional snippet - no need for a sandbox then and if that ever goes away your answer retains value.

Comment: This method does work, however, the reason I want to do this is so that I can work with more complex and numerous code/variables without having to write a different program for every variable.